# Installing memcached on Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-service, memcached

I installed memcached on my dev box which is Windows 7. Everything worked great. Now I want to install on my test server which is Windows Server 2003.

I want to run memcached as a Windows service, so I open a command prompt and type `memcached.exe –d install` just as I did on my dev box, and all it does is sit there with no acknowledgement or confirmation. Does anyone have any idea as to what I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

You will likely need to run this command from an elevated command prompt. Right click on the command prompt in the start menu and go to run as Administrator.

Comment: yes this is needed. I was getting errors like "failed to install service or service already installed", then ran command as administrator and it got installed and started fine